# WPF Custom Control Display the Content

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm creating a custom control in WPF, and I would like to be able to display whatever I put inside it.

A good example would be a `Grid`, `StackPanel`, `DockPanel`

Where you may do something like:

```
<StackPanel>
   <TextBox />
   <Button/>
</StackPanel>
```

And the StackPanel knows about the `TextBox` and the `Button` displays them and reacts accordingly.

**Question:**
How can I display what I put inside my control?

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
<controls:MyControl>
   <Grid>
     <TextBox />
     <Button />
   </Grid>
</controls:MyControl>
```

**Update**
Code behind looks like:

```
public class MyControl:ContentControl
{
   static MyControl()
   {
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyControl),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl)));
   }
}

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend `ContentControl`:

```
public class MyControl : ContentControl {}
```

It has a `Content` property that you can set to any `object`, including a `Grid` or any other `Panel`.

Comment: what should the XAML look like inside the control?

Comment: Exactly like the one you have posted yourself: `<controls:MyControl>...</controls:MyControl>`. Replace `...` with any element or panel.

Comment: so this isn't working. I will update the question

Comment: Your update doesn't follow my suggestion...remove the static constructor and the `ControlTemplate`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234691/discussion-between-3xguy-and-mm8).